# Using filepicker-rails gem, how can I show my users a confirmation that their avatar has been succesfully uploaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, filepicker.io

After uploading an avatar with filepicker.io (filepicker-rails gem) I don't receive any confirmation that it was accepted by the filepicker server.  Anyone know a trick to show my users that their avatar has been uploaded and they can continue filling out their profile form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger a javascript function as an event in the `onchange` option of `filepicker-rails`
gem, and then continue further integration:

```
<%= p.filepicker_field :coverimage_url,dragdrop: true, mimetypes:'image/*', onchange:'sample()' %>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to attach an onchange event in javascript to the input type that will fire when the avatar is uploaded and the rest of the form can continue

Comment: This is what I have on my new.html.erb file: `<div>
     <%= f.label :avatar_url, "Upload Your Profile Picture:" %>
    <%= f.filepicker_field :avatar_url %> <!-- User#avatar_url is a regular string column -->
  </div>`

Comment: So you'll want to add an onchange event on the filepicker_field, either by adding an id and adding it on window.onload or adding it inline as an onchange parameter

Comment: Could you share an example on how you would go about that?  Slightly confused since the filepicker-rails gem documentation on github only gives the full options list as 5 options for filepicker_field (button_text, button_class, mimetypes, container, services)

Comment: Ah sure. You'll want to do this in javascript rather than in ruby directly

Comment: The onchange parameter has been added to the ruby library

Comment: Hi Liyan, can you add your answer as an answer?  Thanks!