# Rails & FilePicker gem - how to obtain metadata of uploaded files?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, filepicker.io, filepicker

I am using [FilePicker gem](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails) and saving files to Amazon S3 bucket. I would like to save metadata of uploaded files into my database, but I stuck how to do that - in the documentation to the gem is written:

> Accessing FilePicker File with OnChange:
>
> When the dialog finishes uploading the file, the javascript code in
>   the onchange field will be run with a special 'event' variable. The
>   variable has a fpfiles (or if not multiple, also fpfile) attribute
>   with information about the files (jQuery users: look under
>   event.originalEvent).

But I am still fighting with a way how to implement fetching these data with jQuery - could I ask you for help with this thing? Upload itself to S3 bucket is working well, but I don't know how to pull metadata of uploaded files.

Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think there already is a similar question in SO with an accepted answer that could help you too: [Using filepicker-rails gem, how can I show my users a confirmation that their avatar has been succesfully uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762581/using-filepicker-rails-gem-how-can-i-show-my-users-a-confirmation-that-their-av)

Basecally you can register an onchange event on the file input field, the first parameter of called function will be the event object holding the meta data.

Comment: The problem is that I am not so skilled to write the JS function for handling and saving these information.

Comment: ok, what you got so far? have you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications ?

Comment: or a complete tutorial: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/10/1/MultiFile-Uploads-and-Multiple-Selects?utm_source=html5weekly&utm_medium=email